# How to remove server headers from the response of application insights request (angular-applicationinsights library)

Tags: angularjs, azure-application-insights

I'm using **angular-applicationinsights** library in my angularjs app. How to remove server and x-powered-by header from the response. Since its document page does not contain any information regarding this, can you please help me on this?
Note: httpinterceptor does not catch its request and responses

Comment: I'm not sure of why you need to do this, but you could do this on the front-end side with Angular Interceptors [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors]. It allows you to intercept the response and modify headers

Comment: if we use angular-applicationinsights library then httpinterceptors does not catch its  request and responses

Comment: Consider also asking this question on corresponding github repository.